# How to find contexts by selenium.find and ignore the comments at the same time?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

```
tag = <span class="_item"><!-- jquery file upload --><!-- multi calendar select --><!-- smooth div scroll -->tachometer<br/>(on site)<!--EndFragment--></span>
```

I want to extract following text without the comments from tag :
`--> tachometer<br/>(on site)`

or as a array like this
`--> ['tachometer',<br/>,'(on site)']`

either is ok for me

I have tried:
`tag.find("span",{'class',"_itemCode"}).contents`

The result will be this:

```
--> [' jquery file upload ',' multi calendar select ', smooth div scroll ','tachometer',<br/>,'(on site)','EndFragment']
```

And if I try this:
`tag.find("span",{'class',"_itemCode"}).text`

The result will be this:
`--> tachometer(on site)`

I need the contents like <br/>,<sup>,<sub>\ to maintain the original format and ignore the comments.